# Close session and start a new one

Tags: php, session

I'm testing the implementation of a security check in my PHP sessions. I can successfuly detect whether the session was started from another IP address and I can successfully start a new session. However, the data from the old session gets copied into the new one! How can I start a blank session while preserving the previous session data for its legitimate owner?

This is my code so far, after lots of failed attempts:

```
<?php

// Security check
if( isset($_SESSION['ip_address']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!=$_SESSION['ip_address'] ){
    // Check failed: we'll start a brand new session
    session_regenerate_id(FALSE);
    $tmp = session_id();
    session_write_close();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_id($tmp);
    session_start();
}

// First time here
if( !isset($_SESSION['ip_address']) ){
    $_SESSION['ip_address'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $_SESSION['start_date'] = new DateTime;
}
```

The official documentation about sessions is terribly confusing :(

**Update:** I'm posting some findings I got through trial and error. They seem to work:

```
<?php

// Load the session that we will eventually discard
session_start();

// We can only generate a new ID from an open session
session_regenerate_id();

// We store the ID because it gets lost when closing the session
$tmp = session_id();

// Close session (doesn't destroy data: $_SESSION and file remains)
session_destroy();

// Set new ID for the next session
session_id($tmp);
unset($tmp);

// Start session (uses new ID, removes values from $_SESSION and loads the new ones if applicable)
session_start();
```

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - session_destroy ?http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php or session_unregister - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php

Comment: @ajreal, you are right: although the name session_destroy() suggests that it removes session data, it doesn't. I'm testing it to find out what it does exactly. Feel free to elaborate this in an answer.

Comment: session_unregister() is deprecated, BTW.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - aiya, 5.3? ...one more, session_unset - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: @ajreal, nope, 5.2; *you* removed the tag one hour ago :)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - oh yeah ... i remove that because **php52** does not sound correct ... since is going to discard after 5.3, better avoid that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset) after [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) to reset `$_SESSION` for the current session:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ip_address']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!=$_SESSION['ip_address']) {
    // Check failed: we'll start a brand new session
    session_regenerate_id(FALSE);
    session_unset();
}
```

Comment: The manual discourages this: *If $_SESSION [...] is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable, i.e. unset ($_SESSION['varname'])*

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: It says “[…] use `unset()` to unregister *a* session variable […]” and “Do NOT unset the whole `$_SESSION` with `unset($_SESSION)` […]”. There is nothing said like *‍do not use `session_unset` to reset the whole `$_SESSION`‍*‍‍.

Comment: Just tested: session_unset() removes the session data. I cannot use it inside the first session because I want to keep it but I guess I can use it inside the second one. Sounds illogical but it should work.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: `session_regenerate_id` basically creates a new session and copies the session data from the old session to the new session. So calling `session_unset` will only affect the new session and not the old one.

Comment: After this code, you still have to call `session_start()` to start a new session, right? Or is it *actually* reset?

Answer (score 2):

when a new user connects to your server, the script should only be able to access that user's session variables. you will want to store other info in a hashed session variable to verify that the session is not being jacked. if it is being jacked, no reason to start a new session, maybe just exit the script with a warning.

here is the function a lot of people use for fingerprinting a session:

```
function fingerprint() {
    $fingerprint = $server_secure_word;
    $fingerprint .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $blocks = explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    for ($i=0; $i<$ip_blocks; $i++) {
        $fingerprint .= $blocks[$i] . '.';
    }
    return md5($fingerprint);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude with a user just because his ISP or DHCP server changed his IP address ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
unset($_SESSION['ip_address'])
```

instead of  'unset($_session)' 
You can also use session_destroy.

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy` **will** destroy session data. For example,

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "test";
session_write_close();
session_start();
// now session is write to the session file
// call session_destroy() will destroy all session data in the file.
session_destroy();
// However the you can still access to $_SESSION here
print_r($_SESSION);
// But once you start the session again
session_start();
// all session data is gone as the session file is now empty
print_r($_SESSION);
```

will output

```
array([test] => "test")array()
```

Comment: I haven't looked into this in several years but, if I recall correctly, the problem with `session_destroy()` was that it would not remove the file (i.e., you could still open a the old session with the old ID). I may test again.