# Why does my session remain?

Tags: php

I must be really stupid because it seems a fairly obvious thing is completely confusing me right now.

I have a session...

ie `$_SESSION['handbag_id'];`

and at a certain point, I need to completely kill this session.

ie

```
// at the start of the page
session_start();

// elsewhere on the same page
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

And yet, I can then go to another page, and do a

```
echo $_SESSION['handbag_id'];
```

And I've still got the same handbag_id as before.

What am I missing? Do I not understand how this works or do I have some server setting that reigns supreme over my desire to destroy its values?

Comment: there is no such function destroy_session();

Comment: is your session id in the url???

Comment: As the Col said, it should be session_destroy

Comment: cheers... in my angst i wrote it wrong above.. in my code it is session_destroy

Comment: @powtac, on the page, where the session is meant to be destroyed, it is in the URL. should that matter?

Comment: Is there any caching activated on the server or any proxy in between?

Comment: My server admin has told me that its just default php configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session functions can be very tricky. To completely kill a session you need to assign a new value to the `$_SESSION` superglobal. Otherwise, all you do is unloading session data from current script. This should work:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_write_close(); // Not required
```

If you also need to open an entirely new session, you can do this:

```
session_regenerate_id(FALSE);
$tmp = session_id();
session_destroy();
session_id($tmp);
unset($tmp);
session_start();
```

**Update:**

A related question you may find useful: [Close session and start a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345014/close-session-and-start-a-new-one)

Comment: Looks a bit mad, I'm pretty sure you can just do this: `session_destroy(); session_start(); session_regenerate_id();`

Comment: @Leigh - It looks mad until you do some testing. Seriously. Your code will probably leave the old session standing, ready to be recovered if you know the old ID.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it, but that session_destroy() throws up an error that there is no session initialised to destroy.

Comment: @KeenLearner - And, is there a session initialised?

Comment: No, it just throws up an error. So I guess problem solved! :) But now I have errors on screen.

Comment: I did. It said there is no session initialised. So a victory there. But my server is printing out the errors to the screen, then it attempts to session_start, but headers are already sent so this throws up more screen errors. I think if I supress the errors I would achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this

```
unset($_SESSION);
```

Do this

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

And finally

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `session_comitt` before printing and see the magic :)