# Destroying PHP Session

Tags: php, security, session, destroy

There are lots of pages on stackoverflow about destorying session. Trust me, I have been reading them all and I came across this: [Why does my session remain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921231/why-does-my-session-remain)

My question is simple, is it really true that I need to do all of the below just to properly destroy a session?

```
$tmp = session_id();
session_destroy();
session_id($tmp);
unset($tmp);
```

This is the only page that suggests such extreme measures. Most pages just suggest `session_destroy();`.

Just to clarify because there seems to be some confusion I am looking for the most efficent method that is effective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Besides destroying a session when you're done with it, you must also generate a new, random session ID when someone logs in successfully to prevent session fixation.

Comment: Great comment @Kerrek, but how do I do that?

Comment: No but based on that question and the one in my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921231/why-does-my-session-remain). @subirkumarsao I asked the question as a separate question because I wanted a clear answer. I am looking for efficiency this person was looking for instructions how to do something. Sorry if I was unclear but others seem to have understood.

Comment: I`m afraid, that you will need to do all of these things if you want your session to be destroyed completely.

Comment: If you have a question on someone's answer raise it there. Why create a new question.

Comment: @Brett: with [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB if I could I would tick you but you made it a comment not an answer. I will put the answer in for you if you have not done so within the next hour. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @GordonM I was not having problems but I wanted to be sure I was doing it right and in an efficient manner. Thanks again for your input :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answers have stopped coming in so I am putting in what I learnt based on all of the answers. This is an aggregation of the various answers. Hopefully it will help others. The most efficient method that is 100% effective for destroying a session is listed below:

```
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) 
{
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
}

$_SESSION = array();
$tmp = session_id();
session_id($tmp);
unset($tmp);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
session_regenerate_id(True); // true indicates the need to delete the old session
```

Thanks to everyone for their help showing me how to do this. This was not a single person effort. I would particularly like to thank @Kerrek SB, @Uday @Dhruvisha. If you have more suggests please feel free to add comments and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

**Example** Destroying a session with $_SESSION

```
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Please see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$s_id = session_id();
echo $s_id;


session_destroy();
session_unset();


session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$s_id = session_id();

?>
```

Try this . It will work.