# Destroying Null Session Variables

Tags: php, html, session

I have created session for my website.To have session started i have wrote following code on each link of website:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['User']))
{
  //session_start();
  $sesvar = $_REQUEST['sid'];
} 
else
{
  $sesvar = " ";
}
```

But when I click log out button session get destroyed.But value of sid(ie parameter to set session variable is set to null.)To destroy session i wrote following code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['out']))
{
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    //unset($_SESSION['User']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:login.html");
    exit;   
}
```

After logout as i get sid=null and after that if i click any link of website the welcome msg is still there with null session variable.Please help.

Comment: You might like to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648565/destroying-php-session as it covers the same ideas.

Comment: what r u use for request data `get` or `post` ?

Comment: Please use the "title" to *summarize* your question, not as the place for your first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

you are actually not using session variable to store the session data.

i assume in below code you are trying to use session variable to store some value

```
$sesvar = $_REQUEST['sid'];
```

you are doing it wrong way, to store any session data you need to store it in super global `$_SESSION` array. so for example.

```
$_SESSION['var'] = $_REQUEST['sid'];
```

and to check or fetch the value you need to check the value in `$_SESSION`