# session_regenerate_id(true) not work

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close session and start a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345014/close-session-and-start-a-new-one)

I use wampserver2.1 php5.3.3, I found session_regenerate_id(true) not work in my script,document says when I set the parameter 'delete_old_sessions' true, there should be a new sid and all the session variables should be deleted, but the fact is after the function, $_session[abc] is still there. did I misunderstand the function,what is my problem?
I appreciate if anyone can help me,

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['abc']=12323;
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo $_SESSION['abc'];                  
?>
```

I thought it should display none, but it outputs:12323

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session_regenerate_id()` updates the current `session id` with a newly generated one. It does not change session variables.

```
echo session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
echo session_id();
```

You should `unset` session to do that:

```
unset($_SESSION); // or
$_SESSION = array();
```

[How to start a new session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#100250):

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id();
unset($_SESSION);
session_start();
```

Comment: thank you, but what is the delete_old_session parameter.  for?

Comment: that deletes the old session file, but it creates a new one and carries the old session vars.

Comment: session_unset() or unset($_session) which is better?

Comment: `session_destroy();` and `unset($_SESSION);` together

Comment: Hi, Mihai, thank you, after tests, I found session_destroy must be invoked before session_regenerate_id, or session_regenerate_id() will not work.

Answer (score 1):

`session_regenerate_id` sends a new cookie but doesn't overwrite the value stored in `$_COOKIE`. After calling `session_destroy`, the open session ID is discarded, so simply restarting the session with `session_start` will re-open the original, though now empty, session for the current request (subsequent requests will use the new session ID). Instead of `session_destroy`+`session_start`, use the `$delete_old_session` parameter to `session_regenerate_id` to delete the previous session data.

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Create a new session, deleting the previous session data. */
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
/* erase data carried over from previous session */
$_SESSION=array();
?>
```

To start a new session and leave the old untouched, simply leave out the argument to `session_regenerate_id`.

*Source: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#107323*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy the session-variables you can perform this: `session_destroy();`
and if you want to get new ID you can `session_regenerate_id();`